If $M$ is a connected topological manifold and $p,q \in M^{o}$, then there exists a homeomorphism which maps $p$ to $q$.
I am stuck in constructing a explicit homeomorphism $f$(say) from a connected manifold $M^{o} = M \backslash \delta M$ to itself such that for $p,q \in M^{o}$ then $f(p) = q$.
I know that that since $p,q \in M^{o}$ we can include them in a open set of $M^{o}$, since a manifold is locally Euclidean, we can join $p$ and $q$ via a path.
How to proceed further??
Edit 1: I was able to come up with a proof of the "general theorem" as pointed in the answer by @quarague
We need to construct a homeomorphism of unit balls, say $U \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ which fix the boundary pointwise and translates the origin to a point $u \in U$.\
Fix a smooth function $\lambda: [0,1) \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(x,y) = 1$ for $x \geq y$ and $\lambda(x,y) = 0$ for $(x + 1)/2 \leq y$
Define $\lVert x \rVert$ to be the norm of vector $x$.
For $u \in U$ define a vector field in the closed unit ball $\Bar{U} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{N} \hspace{3px} | \hspace{3px} \lVert v \rVert \leq 1\}$ by $$f^{u}(v) = \lambda(\lVert u \rVert , \lVert v \rVert)u$$The choice of $\lambda$ ensures that $f^{u} = u$ on the ball of radius $\lVert u \rVert$ with center at the origin and $f^{u} = 0$ outside the ball of radius $(\lVert u \rVert + 1)/2$ with center at the origin.
Let $\{ \theta ^{u,t} : \Bar{U} \rightarrow \Bar{U} \}_{t \in R}$ be the flow determined by $f^{u}$, that is, the unique family of self-diffeomorphisms of $\Bar{U}$ such that $\theta^{u,0} = id$ and $\frac{d\theta^{u,t}}{dt} (v)= f^{u}(v)$ for all $v \in \Bar{U}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now $u$ is a point in $U$, the interior of $\Bar{U}$ and $f^{u}(v) = 0$ whenever $\lVert v \rVert \geq (\lVert u \rVert + 1)/2$, in particular, whenever $v$ is in the boundary of $U$.
Hence $\frac{d\theta^{u,t}}{dt} (v)= 0$ whenever $v$ is a boundary point. $\theta^{u,t}$ is constant with respect to $t$ at the boundary sphere $\partial \Bar{U}$. $\theta^{u,t} = \theta^{u,0} = id$. Hence the boundary is fixed pointwise by this set of diffeomorphisms.
Let $O$ denote the origin. Then since $\lVert O \rVert = 0$ we have $f^{u}(O) = u$ for all $u \in U$. Hence $\theta^{u,t} = tu$. Therefore $\theta^{u,1}(v) : \Bar{U}\rightarrow \Bar{U}$ is the required homeomorphism.
What does it mean to lift the map to get a homeomorphism of the manifold??

I'm not sure how 'explicit' you can get the homeomorphism but this is the general construction. Given a path from $p$ to $q$ in $M$, for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the path is homeomorphic to a disk. Now you invoke a general theorem saying that for two points in the interior of a disk there exists a homeomorphism of the disk that fixes the boundary and maps one point to the other. You can then lift this homeomorphism to the manifold and extend it by the identity map outside of the neighborhood of the path to get a homeomorphism of the entire manifold.

I am a bit confused as to where we used the connectedness hypothesis. And. What is meant by lift this "homeomorphism to the manifold"?

There is a bit more subtlety since the path from $p$ to $q$ cannot cross itself to find such a $\varepsilon$-neighborhood.
